# Change html code through cPanel

Tags: php, html, iframe, cpanel

I had cPanel access to a friend's website but I have never used cPanel. I need to change some html code for some pages.

I found no `.html` files in the File Manager's hierarchy. So I checked the `index.php`.

Only the `index.php` under `public_html` contains html code.

I had an index.php under public_html/maringa and it only contains an iFrame with this [src](http://www.certainWebsite.com.br/maringa).

How can I access the html code behind this iFrame or this page and change it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can either access the code of the source located at "http://www.certainWebsite.com.br/maringa" (if you have access) or scrap the frame and add your own code in the index.php

Comment: is the site linked to in the "src" attribute of the iFrame within the same domain as your friend's website? If not, then it's almost certainly not your code, so you can't alter it. If it is, then you need to find where that page is hosted within the cPanel file manager. It would be somewhere underneath the "public_html" folder, that's where all the web-accessible files are held in a typical cPanel setup.

Comment: @ADyson thank u . My friend's site that am working on is "certainWebsite.com" and the src of the iframe is "certainWebsite.com.br/maringa" .. Knowing that there is a /maringa folder in my File manager ( for certainWebsite.com/maringa) .. is the .br subdomain hosted in another server and I need to ask for access to it ??

Comment: .br is a top level domain not a subdomain, so yes it's more than likely hosted in another account somewhere. Unless both domain names resolve to the same IP address?

Comment: they do resolve the same IP address..

Comment: in that case then I would say the two sites are both hosted within the same cPanel. Why it's set up like this with an iFrame I don't understand, it seems unnecessary. But anyway you should find some contents within the "public_html/maringa" folder in your cPanel file manager.

Comment: yes I found out that they are both managed from the same hosting account.. I had a language problem communicating with the brazilian owner of the website and it's resolved ! Thank you for your help anyway..